# Intellij compile error: java: error: release version 5 not supported

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pom.xml

I have the following pom.xml file and its not compiling and running the test (selenium). I am using maven.

I have java version 15 but set settings to 11 due to some answers I have seen here. Could this be a problem?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-driver-3-cross-browser-framework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I do not know what else to write, kindly let me know how I can help you to answer my question.

Comment: Update the question with the complete text based error stack trace

Comment: Why do you have the Maven compiler set to 1.8 and the release set to 11? Should the Maven compiler settings also be 11?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the answers, my question was solved by this website's method #1.

https://dev.to/techgirl1908/intellij-error-java-release-version-5-not-supported-376

Comment: Mine was solved by the same website's method, but I had to use methods #1 AND  #3.

Comment: Mine was solved by the same website's method using #1

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your pom and amend some artifacts as below,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sample-Mvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Test class, and it works fine to me. Make sure that `geckodriver` is installed in your system.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10L);
        try {
            driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3>div")));
            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Thangavel Loganathan, I am still getting the error message after using your pom.xml config file